# Can an electrostatic loudspeaker be considered as a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, speakers, physics

A basic capacitor works as two parallel plates carrying opposite charges and have an electrostatic force holding the charges in place (without making any contact); can't an electrostatic loudspeaker be considered a capacitor since it works by having a charged diaphragm between two plates of opposite charge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an electrostatic speaker is a capacitor.  From the Wikipedia article ["Electrostatic loudspeaker"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_loudspeaker):

> The electrostatic construction is in effect a capacitor, and current
>   is only needed to charge the capacitance created by the diaphragm and
>   the stator plates

There are, as you might expect, [microphones that are essentially capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Condenser_microphone) too.